# How can I load data variables that accessible to all views but get initialised after data available in database?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating API with Django rest framework. I've one table which will be used as types for the products. Another table which will map that types with the product. consider it as `producttypesmapping` table. So, I'm creating product type update endpoint. which will only update the `producttypesmapping`.

The issue is I've used ChoiceField() in the serializer. So I need the tuple of tuples variable to prevent from storing unwanted values. which will be initialized in util.py and to make it dynamic it loads directly by querying the `producttypes` table. So, I only have to query the data only once.

```
TAG_CHOICES_TYPE_ONE = []

tags = ProductTypes.objects.filter(tag_type_id=1).values('id', 'value')


for index, item in enumerate(tags):
    TAG_CHOICES_TYPE_ONE.append((item["id"], item["value"]))

TAG_CHOICES_TYPE_ONE = tuple(TAG_CHOICES_TYPE_ONE)
```

But the problem is utils.py executed before the even the `producttypes` initialized with any data.

Comment: Why are you doing the intermediate table by hand if you can use `ManyToManyField`?

Comment: Yes this definitely seems like something you shouldn't be doing. Why do you think you need to?

Comment: It is a junction table. `producttypes`. producttypes has types and we want load  rows that are type=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, unless you want to attach some additional data about the mapping, your mapping model shouldn't be necessary. Simply use a `ForeignKey` or a `ManyToManyField`.

Then, you should consider using a [`PrimaryKeyRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) instead of a `ChoiceField`. This field takes a [queryset](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#the-queryset-argument) as an argument, which will help you limit your choices. If you chose a `ChoiceField` to be able to get a nice display in the browsable API, you can achieve the same by creating a [string representation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.__str__) for your model.

Comment: In the mapping table, I only need a reference of the object that is type=1 from the type table. Yes, mapping table does have related(relationship) information.